# How to implement nested function calls template in Mustache?

Tags: java, mustache

I wanted to have a behaviour like this

```
{{md5(sha1(base64Encoding({{someValue}})))}}
{{sha1(base64Encoding({{someValue}}))}}
```

Can I achieve this kind of behaviour using mustache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Mustache is a logic-less templating engine.
You will have to do those hashing computations in your code and use the outcome in Mustache.